# Javascript Printing a page while looping through objects

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing

I have a webpage that I'm using to print 'pages' of data as PDF files via the firefox 'Print to File' printer on my laptop.  The code I'm invoking is as follows:

```
   document.body.controls.cmdPrint.click = function ()                              // Create a function that will be called when this object is clicked upon
   {if (parseInt(document.body.controls.page.innerHTML) !== 0)                      //  If we are not on the Front Cover
    {return false;}                                                                 //   Function complete: Abnormal Termination
    document.body.controls.style.pointerEvents = 'none';                            //  Lock down the controls so they cannot be interfered with
    do                                                                              //  Do...
    {window.print();                                                                //   Print this page
//   document.body.sleep(); // Removed as this does not work as expected (see below...)
    } while (document.body.controls.cmdNext.click())                                //   ...while we are able to advance.
    document.body.controls.style.pointerEvents = '';                                //  Release the controls lockout
    this.blur();                                                                    //  Blur the focus
    return true;};                                                                  // Function complete: Normal Termination
```

When executing, the pages flip as expected (as the cmdNext.click() function returns a true when successful and a false when it's on the last page and trying to advance), but it runs too quickly.  Namely every odd page is caught out, as the 'printer' is unavailable....the window.print() is being released before the printer is ready for the next page.

I tried slowing down execution by adding a reference to a secondary function within the loop (now commented out), but this just locks up the CPU and keeps the printer from processing in another thread....so it's not a valid solution.  This function (which I wrote but did not provide the expected cushioning to allow odd pages to print) is as follows.

```
   document.body.sleep = function (delay)                                           // Create a new function
   {delay = delay || 1;                                                             //  Default to a delay of 1 second
    var timestamp = new Date();                                                     //  Get current time
    timestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() + (delay * 1000));                     //  Add in the delay (in seconds)
    while (new Date() < timestamp) {}                                               //  While we are waiting for the delay, do nothing
    return true;};                                                                  // Function complete: Normal Termination
```

Basically what I need is a way to hold loop execution long enough to let the 'Print to File' to go through before the next window.print() is called.  Using the sleep function above also keeps the window.print() from running even though (when I was trying to use it as a fix) I had put the call to this function immediately after the window.print() command.

So I ask, can anyone here supply a fix for this project so I don't have to manually cycle through each page (which could get annoyingly temporally expensive with a page count above 10)?

As it is currently, when the second page tries to print, I get the popup window holding an error from firefox: "Printer Error - Some printing functionality is not currently available."  Tracking this down lead to PERR_NOT_AVAILABLE....probably because the printer (Print to File) is busy printing the prior page....so I just need to wait for that to resolve before going to the next printing.  An error handler to catch this PERR_NOT_AVAILABLE instead of letting it bounce to the user (me) as a popup window that has to be clicked out of would be nice, though a spammy way of getting the pages to print in sequence as quickly as the Print to File system can process them.

If window.print() actually returned an error in this condition, I could just rerun the command...

Answer (score 0):

In my experimentation, I found this workaround...it's quite fairly considered a kludge, but in the absence of a more elegant solution, it works.

```
document.body.controls.cmdPrint.click = function ()                              // Create a function that will be called when this object is clicked upon
{if (parseInt(document.body.controls.page.innerHTML) !== 0)                      //  If we are not on the Front Cover
 {return false;}                                                                 //   Function complete: Abnormal Termination
 document.body.controls.style.pointerEvents = 'none';                            //  Lock down the controls so they cannot be interfered with
 window.onafterprint = function ()                                               //  Set up a handler for after a print operation
 {setTimeout(function ()                                                         //   Run a delayed operation
  {if (document.body.controls.cmdNext.click())                                   //    Move to next page and if this is successful
   {window.print();                                                              //    Continue printing
    return false;}                                                               //    Function complete: Still Printing
   do                                                                            //   Do nothing...
   {} while (document.body.controls.cmdPrevious.click())                         //    ...while we cycle back to the start
   document.body.controls.style.pointerEvents = '';                              //   Release the controls lockout
   this.blur();                                                                  //   Blur the focus
   window.onafterprint = function () {};                                         //   Remove this handler
   return true;}, 2000);};                                                       //   Function complete: Normal Termination
 window.print();                                                                 //  Begin printing the page
 return true;};                                                                  // Function complete: Normal Termination
```

If a page is too complex to print to PDF in 2 seconds, that 2000 figure in the setTimeout() will have to be increased to account for it.  For my test case (the current 7 page document), 2000 seems to be the sweet spot between not-working and spitting out pages as quickly as Firefox will permit on my system.